# jQuery Scrolltop value rewrite to activate at 100% instead of topvalue?

Tags: jquery

I writing a script that activates at scroll but regarding the screen minimize and size different I would like this to by activated in % instead of 900 top value

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 900)
```

How can I rewrite this to activate at 100% instead of 900 of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want condition to be true when you reach the bottom of the page, you could try this :

```
if($('body').height() > $(window).height() && 
   $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height()-$(window).height()))
```

EDIT : see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tMy9J/

Comment: no i have a picture that takes 100% of the start screen and i want a true answer when this picture is over

Comment: @JosefCarlsson Ok, so `if($(window).scrollTop() > $('img').height())` should work

Comment: can i use this targeting a special #id?

Comment: @JosefCarlsson Of course you can : `$('#yourId').height()` will return the height of your element of id `yourId`.